# Storing unicode like ✅ from form to db

Tags: sql-server, unicode, vbscript, asp-classic

I cannot get unicode characters from form to db

The webdesigner/seo-guy wants to use an unicode character ✅ (9989, which shows up as a whute checkmark in a green box.

The data in the CMS is entered through a form, both a

If I paste the ✅ directly into database, using Mssql SSMS, character is seem in the field, and unicode(field) is 9989.

The asp can retrieve the ✅ and put it as value in the html form.

I post the form, the page shows the form sends the correct code, ✅. the page then post the contents and retrieves it again, but the value stored is not ✅ but "?", char 63.

So DB->form is ok, form->DB is broken.

My page starts with

```
<% Response.Charset="UTF-8"%>
<% Response.codepage="65001" %>

<form method='post' accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The field in the db is nvarchar, SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI though I tried Danish_Norvegian too, no difference.

**edit**

I have the insert wrapped in a function, but unwrapped it's like this:

```vb
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = connection 
cmd.CommandType = 1 ' adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "update t_kat set meta_title=?,meta_description=? where id=?"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("",adVarChar,1,255, request.form("meta_title"))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("",adVarChar,1,255, request.form("meta_description"))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("",adInteger,1,255, request.form("id")

cmd.Execute
```

**EDIT 2**
It works if I say `server.htmlencode(request.form("meta_description"))` but then ✅æøåÆØÅ gets stored in the db as `&#9989;&#230;&#248;&#229;&#198;&#216;&#197;` which I'd rather avoid.
In worst case, id accept the "wierd" characters as `&#9989` but I prefer the other characters as-is. But I don't think there is an option to select which characters are replaced.

I could do a replace of each "weird" charactes to `%#nnnn`format (I don't think he uses that many) in the CMS frontend before storing, but I'd rather not go there either.

Comment: Show us *how* you're insert the data. The character can be stored, and retreived fine: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4a6d182e2a9bb04f57fd55ff0c47c1b)

Comment: This problem IS reproducible by using the wrong fieldtype, adVarChar instead of adVarWchar

Comment: Yes, but when I made that comment, it was 20 minutes before you showed us *how* you inserting the data, which I why I asked how you were inserting it. Why others voted that it had no repro after your edit, I cannot comment on, but mine was before. I have, however, voted to reopen this. Though, this is now very likely a duplicate of another question where someone has used the wrong data type. Just like there are 100's of duplicates of "Why does `SELECT '✅'` return `?`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
The parameter should be the right type:

`cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("",adVarWChar,1,255, request.form("meta_title")`

`adVarWChar` instead of `adVarChar`

I think only quotes are in need of being replaced when using the data in a input text form

`<input type='text' name="meta_title" value="<%=replace("""","&quot;",res("meta_title"))%>">`

This is to prevent invalid HTML like
`<input type="text" value="The 11'8" bridge">`

Turning it into `<input type="text" value="The 11'8&quot; bridge">`

If used as text, the `<` needs escaping;

`<B>one<two</B>`